# Insert Audio at Every 60 Seconds and Delay Another Audio Stream until the End of the Inserted Audio with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, editing

I am trying to use FFmpeg to insert an audio clip at every 60 seconds into an audio file. I also want to delay the original audio stream  until the end of the inserted audio clip , so that the inserted audio doesn't overlap with the original audio.

I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve splitting the original file into 60 seconds videos and then combine then together , as it makes the following steps, that I have to do, many times more complex.

### Possible Solution:

I think the `-ss` flag could be used to set the timestamp of the inserted audio clip to 60 seconds after the end of the last segment. Then, I could use a delay filter to delay the original audio track until the end of the inserted audio clip.

However I am not sure how to create command. Mainly the part , where we apply this filter at every 60 seconds intervals.

Thanks for any help in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concat demuxer

```
#!/bin/bash

f="../input.mp3"
a="in.mp3"

# get duration of input
d=$(ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$f")

# get seconds
d=${d%.*}
echo $d

# variables
i=0
o=60

# create list of inputs
l="list.txt"
echo "ffconcat version 1.0" > $l
echo "file '$f'" >> $l
echo "outpoint $o" >> $l
# increase variables by 60 sec
i=$o
((o+=60))
while (( $i < $d )); do
    # insert audio clip
    echo "file '$a'" >> $l
    # add audio next 60 sec
    echo "file '$f'" >> $l
    echo "inpoint $i" >> $l
    echo "outpoint $o" >> $l
    # increase variables by 60 sec
    i=$o
    ((o+=60))
done
cat $l

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "$l" -c copy output.mp3 -y

ffplay output.mp3
```

Comment: could you please explain me, how this solves it , so I can extend and use it to my needs?